# Extract winmail.dat info not attachments

Tags: linux, tnef, winmail.dat

I have been using `TNEF` for some time to extract attachments from `RTF` emails sent by `Outlook`, but I was wondering is there a way to extract the information about additional information contained within?

To be more precise I am talking about the Voting Buttons and anything else it might contain?

Comment: I'm the author of the tnef CLI application (not sure if that is the one you were talking about). My app does not let you do what you want out of the box. However you could base new work off of its code or use its very verbose debug output to get information about the specific parts you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already looked into that and it does provide the data I need in some cases but not all. I will use that worst case even though it does not seem to always work for some reason, probably due to differences in Outlook versions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but this answer might be helpful for some new users.

We could extract the rich text (Voting buttons, image resize widgets which are part of email body ..etc) from winmail.dat using the Linux command line tool TNEF.

[TNEF Tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tnef)

**tnef -w --save-body winmail.dat**
Then it will fetch the email body into file message.html, if we give the option **yes or y**
extract **message.html?**

Hope this helps for some one new to TNEF format and winmail.dat